# Navbar with fixed position staying on the top while header disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make navbar with fixed position. At the top of the page the navbar should be under the header and after scrolling down when header is no longer visible the navbar should be at the top of the page. How can I do that? When I try to do it after scrolling down between the navbar and top of the page is still the height of the header(even though it is no longer visible).

Here is my css:

```
header{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
    float:left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: green;  
}
main{

background-color: blue;
height: 1500px;
margin-left:15%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top:50px;

}
```

and jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pg2kwk5e/

Comment: Just to clear, do you want that both nav bar and header appears while scrolling?

Comment: I want navbar always visible and header only while page is scrolled to the top

Comment: You will have to use javascript to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the `nav` element with javascript after scrolling a certain amount.

I've used `Jquery` as it's faster and easier to show this in action.

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pg2kwk5e/3/)

I'm just adding a class `.fixedTop` to the `nav` after the window scrolls more than 150 pixels, the class itself just has `top:0;margin0;` to move the absolute positioned element to the top and remove the margin which was set before.

Code:

```
var $nav = $("nav"),


$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
     $nav.addClass('fixedTop');
  } else {
     $nav.removeClass('fixedTop');
  }

})
```

CSS:

```
.fixedTop {
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But what if I would like the navbar move more smoothly and while the header is visible at least in some part I would like the navbar to be always 50px under it?

Comment: You can apply a transition so when the `navbar` moves into place it dosent do it abruptly something like `transition: all 0.2s ease-in;` will work fine , i've added it to the example. As for it being always 50px under im not sure that there is a simple css solution for that.